# Can reCaptcha image be restricted to numbers - i.e. no text?

Tags: php

I know there is a message saying this cannot be done.  However, I don't know which year the question was asked and reCaptcha may have been modified since then.  Sometimes a numeric image is displayed already.  I'd like to make all images similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the following URLs. This might help you

http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2013/10/recaptcha-just-got-easier-but-only-if.html

http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/wiki/HowToSetUpRecaptcha

Comment: `[...]This might help you` shouldn't you know if these links help if you suggest them? Where does this explain how to just display numbers in the reCaptcha? When you write answers do not just link to a page, create a full answer with the explanation how to solve the problem.